# How to increase BACKEND_BUCKETS limit?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've used up my initial BACKEND_BUCKETS resource quota limit of 3.0 and I can't figure out how to request the quota increase. I've found the 'Google Compute Engine Quota Change Request Form' but unfortunately it doesn't contain a backend buckets input field. I suspect it's because backend buckets are an alpha feature. Is there a way of requesting a limit increase without purchasing a Silver or Gold support level?

Comment: As you mentioned this feature is in alpha, there are no forms  at the moment to request increase for this quota. In fact it might not be possible but you could try to open a case with the [billing team](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6282346?hl=en) to see if they can help you.

Comment: Thank you @Carlos. I've ended up creating a new project and requesting the alpha access on that project which in turn gave me 3 additional backend buckets.

Comment: Please consider posting a self-answer with your solution, so that the community can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has added support for BACKEND_BUCKETS to their [Quota increase request](https://docs.google.com/a/reveel.it/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe291Fkdz1BuSe33-lSWXe5L_WmVhdeTq0WIE-wlREGz9zkDA) form. Now all you have to do is send a quota increase request via the form and Google will update your quota limits within a couple of hours.